# Is this a violation of the strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, type-punning

Consider this C code:

```
extern void CheckIfPtrInHeap( void* p );

void TakePtr( void** p, size_t n )
{
  for( size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
    CheckIfPtrInHeap( p[ i ] );
}

typedef size_t val_t[ 6 ];
extern void* stack_top;

void Func()
{
  val_t val;

  TakePtr( (void**) &val, ( (size_t) stack_top - (size_t) &val ) / sizof( size_t ) );
}
```

It compiles fine with gcc 4.8, mingw 4.7, cl 18.00. Which might make sense because just from the looks of it I'd say there is no violation here: yes there are 2 pointers pointing to the same variable, but the second one's value is immediately cast to a size_t which requires a temporary, so the pointer itself cannot be used inside the function TakePtr.

Q1: Is my assumption above correct? And if it is, does this mean there really is no violation, or rather that the compiler figured out there is none while techically (i.e. following the standard by the letter) there is a violation (still two pointers to same variable being dereferenced)?

Q2: I stumbled upon this while using the mingw cross-compiler version 4.2.1 on linux, it raises `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules` for the line with TakePtr. So the second question is actually like the first but in other words: is this compiler correct, or is it a bug, or would one rather call it 'compiler being too strict'?

Q3: Wanting compilation without warnings for all aforementioned compilers, what would the most correct fix in code be (maybe not just for this case, but for a more general one where there is a violation of the rule and void** pointers are used)? It seems there are multiple ways to silence the compiler:

```
union { val_t* r; void** ptr; } cast_ = { &val };
void** ptr = cast_.ptr;
```

or

```
void* p1 = (void*) &val;
void** ptr = &p1;
```

or even

```
void** ptr = (void**) (void*) &val;
```

or maybe (to tell the compiler 'hey I know what I'm doing', at least if I understood `restrict` correctly)

```
void* restrict p1 = (void*) &val;
void** ptr = &p1;
```

or

```
val_t* p1 = &val;
void** p2 = NULL;
memcpy( p2, p1, sizeof( p1 ) );
```

Comment: This depends on what exactly `TakePtr()` is doing. Why are you casting a pointer to `size_t`? The correct cast would be to `uintptr_t`. What does `TakePtr()` do with its arguments?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves in the actual code `TakePtr` does mark&sweep garbage collection, so it takes a pointer to the stack for instance, and the length - this is just code to reproduce, the actual function takes something like `(size_t) stack_top - (size_t) &vals`

Comment: Does it ever dereference the pointer?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves see edit, added a more complete implementation of TakePtr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strict aliasing rules are simply the fact that it is illegal to access an object of one type through an lvalue of another type (with exceptions for things like `void*` and `char*`, and other obvious things). No more, no less.

Merely having two, or three, or 10000 pointers to the same object at the same time, whether they are all of the same type or not, has nothing to do with the strict aliasing rules. You need to dereference one of them for the violation to happen.

This is also totally unrelated to the `restrict` keyword, which is not concerned with types at all, but simply informs the compiler that a pointer is unique.

`TakePtr` is in violation regardless of what games are played with the second argument, simply because it accesses an array of `size_t` as if it were an array of `void*`.

Unions won't help, because assignment to one field of the union and then accessing a field of another type is not legal either. *Exactly* the same bad things that happen when dereferencing wrong pointers, happen in this case too.

The only semi-correct way to do access a value through an lvalue of different type is via `memcpy`. Not that the results of that are automatically well-defined. A bit pattern that represents a valid value of type A may not represent a valid value of type B. But if this is not the case, then you can memcpy it and it is guaranteed to deliver the correct value.

Comment: Well that clears things out a bit - so does this mean the compiler raising a warning about the cast is very much right? And a proper solution would be to make TakePtr use size_t** as argument?

Comment: No, please, no `size_t**`. `size_t**` points to an object of type `size_t*`. You don't *have* an object of type `size_t*` you can point to. You have an array of `size_t`. Use `size_t*` to access it.

Comment: What I actually have is a piece of memory of which I know it contains pointers, but there is no way of knowing what they point to since they were obtained using some form of malloc. The thing is, this piece of memory happens to be passed to me as an array of size_t (well might not actually be size_t but rather an integer that is guiaranteed to have the same size as a pointer) and I cannot change it..

Comment: So you have something passed to you as an array of `size_t`. What on God's green earth makes you try to access it via a pointer of type `size_t**`?

Comment: By the way the fact that you have an array of pointers punned to an array of integers means that there's a violation of aliasing rules already and it's a bit too late to worry.

Comment: Well, it's a garbage collector for C which scans stack and bss section for pointers allocated on it's heap, somewhat based on http://www.hboehm.info/gc/ I guess. It gets the stack for instance by copying register contents in such a size_t array. It works, no doubt, but it has to do all kinds of funky stuff to be able to access it. But you're probably right: it seems too late to be worrying about this case when the evil has been done already..

Comment: What are the exceptions to the strict aliasing rules for `void*`?  I thought the only exception was for `char*`.